# Git marking unchanged lines as changed

Tags: git, diff, newline, commit

I am committing files through Git Gui, and this is what I see:

```
@@ -1,14 +1,14 @@
-* {
-   margin:0;
-   padding:0;
-   text-align: left;
-   outline:0; /* chrome */
-}
-table {
-   table-layout: fixed;
-   border-spacing: 0;
-   border-collapse: collapse;
-}
-html {
-   height:100%;
+* {
+   margin:0;
+   padding:0;
+   text-align: left;
+   outline:0; /* chrome */
+}
+table {
+   table-layout: fixed;
+   border-spacing: 0;
+   border-collapse: collapse;
+}
+html {
+   height:100%;
 }
\ No newline at end of file
```

Basically it marks all lines as deleted and then again as added. This is obviously false, I only changed one or two lines, if anything.

I suspect something with newlines, and Git not detecting any newlines. I am working on a Windows machine, using Sublime text editor... What can I do?

Comment: It's very likely that the line endings in the file changed between revisions.

Comment: Sounds plausible. I committed the above, really did not want to but I can't let Git get in my way for too long, and now the problem is gone. I can't figure out what would've caused the linebreaks to change.
I wish there was an option to make Git ignore different linebreak formats. There was an option to convert linebreaks automatically, but I did not pick that... I'd rather have them stay whatever they are.

Comment: Check the settings in Sublime.  What are the other developers using and do any of them have a different line break setting?

Answer (score 1):

If you configure the core.autocrlf option, that only affects files that you download ie someone else's commits that you are downloading. Files created by others and checked in with different line-endings will, imo, remain with that line-ending character.